# Solving $\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x+1},0\right)=2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x+1},e^y\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

Suppose $y=f(x)$ is defined implicitly as the solution of the following equation

$$\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x+1},0\right)=2 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{x+1},e^y\right)$$

Where $\Gamma$ is the upper incomplete Gamma [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

The plot of $f(x)$ looks linear, how do I solve for the slope/intercept?

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-gamma-breakeven.nb)

Motivation: this gives the range of values for which the loss curve of gradient descent is well modeled by the power law. Equivalently, when [generalized exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Generalization) is well approximated by $x^{n-1}$ term

Comment: looks like the intercept is somewhere around 20 :)

Comment: Note where $(0,0)$ is on the graph in relation to the OP’s graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Inverse gamma regularized $Q^{-1}(a,x)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inversegammaregularized) gives:

$$y=\ln\left(Q^{-1}\left(\frac1{x+1},\frac12\right)\right)$$

where the $\frac12$ implies a connection with the [gamma distribution median](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gamma+distribution+median). Therefore the $y$ intercept of $f(x)$ is:

$$\left(0, \ln\left(Q^{-1}\left(1,\frac12\right)\right)\right)=(0,\ln(\ln(2)))$$

Using oblique asymptote [limits](https://math24.net/asymptotes.html):

$$y\sim mx+a=-\ln(2)(x+1)-\gamma\\m=\lim_{x\to0}\frac y
x=\lim_{x\to0}x\ln\left(\sqrt[x]\frac{x!}2\right)=-\ln(2)\\a=\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\left(Q^{-1}\left(\frac1{x+1},\frac12\right)\right)+\ln(2)x=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(x!)}x-\ln(2)=-\gamma-\ln(2)$$

with the $a$ limit [using](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5Blog%281%2F2+%CE%93%281+%2B+1%2F%281+%2B+x%29%29%5E%281+%2B+x%29%29%2Cx-%3Einfty%5D) and $m$ limit [using](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5Bln%282%5E%28-1+-+x%29+%CE%93%281+%2B+1%2F%281+%2B+x%29%29%5E%281+%2B+x%29%29%2Fx%2Cx-%3Einfty%5D) [$Q^{-1}(a,x)\sim \sqrt[a]{(1-x)a!}$](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/InverseGammaRegularized/06/01/03/0001/) with the [Euler Mascheroni constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=eulergamma). Using the OP’s window:

[image]

Comment: Nice to know the connection to Gamma distribution median. There looks to be an compact and tight bound for it [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/285830/217)